# The 633 reducible configurations of the 4 color Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, math-history, coloring

Ken Appel died a few days ago, and I wanted to see how long it took to perform the [four color theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) proof now, with modern systems. At the [Four Color Theorem](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/FC/) page, there is a link given for the configurations, but it seems non-functional.

So, does anyone have a working link?  Alternately, if someone has access to the with the discharging program, could you run it on a 2013-era system and announce how long the proof takes to run?

Comment: If you run the program, please return and post your results. I'd be very interested to hear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the links on [this page](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/FC/ftpinfo.html).  (It's actually linked to in the "Pointers" section of the Four Color Theorem page.) In case that site goes down to, the content has also been backed up at arxiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6481) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6485).

Comment: Yep, that's it.